# Unset define in cppcheck analyze from cmake generated command

Tags: c++, cmake, cppcheck

I have project which i check with cppcheck 1.90, but i want to unset few defines, because it takes a lot of time to check with all defines.

Example: `tests.cpp`:

```
int main() {
  int x,y;
#ifdef A
  x = 5;
#else
  x = 10;
#endif

#ifdef B
  y = 5;
#else
  y = 10;
#endif

#ifdef C
  y = 5*x;
#else
  y = 10*x;
#endif

  int c = x+y;
}
```

When i work with file without project - there is no problem:

```
cppcheck ../tests.cpp --force -UB
Checking ../tests.cpp ...
Checking ../tests.cpp: A...
Checking ../tests.cpp: C...
```

I unset define B - and cppcheck don't check compile path with B.
But how to do it with file generated from cmake project?

```
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
cppcheck --project=./compile_commands.json --force -UB
Checking /home/builder/bugs/test_cppcheck/tests.cpp ...
Checking /home/builder/bugs/test_cppcheck/tests.cpp: A...
Checking /home/builder/bugs/test_cppcheck/tests.cpp: B...
Checking /home/builder/bugs/test_cppcheck/tests.cpp: C...
```

As i can see cppcheck is ignored "-U" key. Is any way to unset define in that case?

Add cmakefile for test example:

```
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

project(tests)

set(SRC
    tests.cpp
)

set(NAME test)
add_executable(${NAME} ${SRC})
```

Comment: Have you tried setting C++ flag ? CMakeLists file `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-D*your_flags*")`, posting your CMakeLists file can be helpful.

Comment: This is an issue with `cppcheck` and you most probably ]should report a bug with them.

Comment: @joepol, thanks! But better to unset define!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an option to edit the CMakeLists file only once and pass arguments as needed, To achieve this you should

> In the CMakeLists file add:

`set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} *hard_coded_flags*")`

> Command line :

When calling `cmake` from command line you add `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS = -UB=1` (or any other **cppcheck** flag), this will concatenate `-UB=1`  the to the `hard_coded_flags`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to have `cmake` run `cppcheck` itself. This can be done by setting `CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK` (see the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_CPPCHECK.html)). You can either set `CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK` in your `CMakeLists.txt`, or you can set it on the command-line that invokes `cmake`.

This does have some disadvantages (for example, each source file is checked individually, so cross-file checking doesn't work).

But there are several advantages:

- No need to invoke `cppcheck` separately.
- If you set `CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK` in your `CMakeLists.txt`, you can also add `cppcheck` command-line options to control what it does. In your case, you could add `-UB`.
- This helps encapsulate all knowledge of how to build and check your project into a single file (`CMakeLists.txt`).

I typically follow a pattern something like this in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
option(ENABLE_CODE_ANALYSIS "Run code analysis" OFF)
if(ENABLE_CODE_ANALYSIS)
    find_program(cppcheck cppcheck)
    message(STATUS "cppcheck    ${cppcheck}")
    if(NOT (cppcheck MATCHES "NOTFOUND"))
        set(CMAKE_CXX_CPPCHECK "${cppcheck}"
            "--enable=all"
            "--inconclusive"
            "--inline-suppr"
            "--quiet"
            "--suppress=missingInclude"
            "--suppress=unmatchedSuppression"
            "--suppress=unusedFunction"
            "--template='{file}:{line}: warning: {id} ({severity}): {message}'")
    endif()
endif(ENABLE_CODE_ANALYSIS)
```

Then you can do code analysis by doing `cmake -DENABLE_CODE_ANALYSIS=ON`.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible decision is change CMakeLists file(unsetting define):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(tests)
set(SRC
    tests.cpp
)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-UB=1")
set(NAME test)
add_executable(${NAME} ${SRC})
```

And output is:

```
$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/builder/bugs/test_cppcheck/build
$ cppcheck --project=./compile_commands.json --force
Checking /home/builder/bugs/test_cppcheck/tests.cpp ...
Checking /home/builder/bugs/test_cppcheck/tests.cpp: A...
Checking /home/builder/bugs/test_cppcheck/tests.cpp: C...
```

There is no "B" path checking.
But if exist solution without changing CMakeLists - it would be better.